# In background of ImageView add Lottie with animation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, animation, lottie

I have a LottieAnimationView in my xml file. I want to add custom image that comes dynamically from backend(avatar image) in that lottie animation view, I mean in lottie animation view add image in its background. This is my LottieAnimationView:

```
  <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                                android:id="@+id/lottie_animation"
                                android:layout_width="110dp"
                                android:layout_height="110dp"
                                app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/custom"
                                app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/photo_animation"
                                app:lottie_loop="true"
                                app:lottie_speed="2.5" />
```

But its only showing my animation, not showing imageview at all.
Could you post any ideas how can I handle it?

Comment: Overlap the animation view and `ImageView`. Use a `FrameLayout` and place both the view inside the layout with equal dimensions.